# Doctrine error with LifecycleEventArgs arguments

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to use Listener in my project with `postLoad` method but I got an error

```
 [TypeError] App\Company\Infrastructure\Persistence\ORM\EventListener\LoadLicensesListener::postLoad(): Argument #1 ($args) must be of type Do
ctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, App\Company\Domain\Entity\Company given, called in D:\OpenServer\domains\project\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doc
trine\ORM\Event\ListenersInvoker.php on line 108
```

My Listener

```
  use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

  final class LoadLicensesListener
   {
    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();

        if (!$entity instanceof Copmany) {
            // Something to do
            $licenses = $entity->relatedLicenses;           
            $entity->initializeObject($licenses);
        }

    }
}
```

And I registered it in `Company.orm.xml`

```
   <entity-listeners>
            <entity-listener class="App\Company\Infrastructure\Persistence\ORM\EventListener\LoadLicensesListener">
                <lifecycle-callback type="postLoad" method="postLoad"/>
            </entity-listener>
        </entity-listeners>
```

services.yml

```
   App\Company\Infrastructure\Persistence\ORM\EventListener\LoadLicensesListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad, connection: default }
```

Where did I go wrong? Maybe I misunderstood the documentation - [Symfony Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-listeners) or [Doctrine Events](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/events.html)
Or I should do something in `services.yml` because I've changed a folder with EventListeners?
 `"doctrine/orm": "2.8.4"`

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine provide different type of listeners, "Default" event listener and Entity Listener, here your registered an entity listener in your file `Company.orm.xml` and also for the same class a "default" event listener.

Choose which type of listener you want and register it according to the documentation.

If you choose a Entity Listener then the first argument will be the Entity itself, that's why you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it looks like you've configured it wrong.

try to implement `postLoad` method **inside** your Campany.php (Note! Without any params) and see what it outputs.

```php
class Company {

// ...

public function postLoad() {
 dump(__METHOD__);
}

}
```

also take a look at this https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html and this one https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html
I am unfortunately not familiar with `xml`-configs, so I can't spot anything suspicious.

As always, there are several ways to get it done:

- simple EntityLifeCycles ([docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks)) - useful for basic stuff and if you don't rely on additional services for this particular task. Logic applies only for that specific Entity.
- an `Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber` with `getSubscribedEvents` - more advanced and flexible. One logic could be applied for several entities
- an EventListener.

So here are examples for symfony 4.4 and doctrine 2.7:

1. Entity LifeCylcles:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class Company {
   /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

   // ... props and methods

   /**
    * @ORM\PostLoad()
    */
   public function doStuffAfterLoading(): void
   {
        // yor logic
        // you can work with $this as usual
        // no-return values!
        
        // dump(__METHOD__);
   }

}
```

with these annotations no extra entries in `services.yml|xml` necessary

2. - [Subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-subscriber-class) - to apply same logic for one or several Entities

```php
use App\Entity\Company;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

final class PostLoadSubscriber implements EventSubscriber {

  public functuin __construct()
  { 
    // you can inject some additional services if you need to
    // e.g. EntityManager  

  }

  public function getSubscribedEvents()
  {
     return [
         Events::postLoad,
     ];
  }

 public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
 {
     // check if it's right entity and do your stuff
    $entity = $args->getObject();
    if ($entity instanceof Company) {
     // magic...
    }
 }

}
```

You need to register this `PostLoadSubscriber` as a service in `services.yaml|xml`